# How to execute "svn diff" inside some custom Junit as part of Teamcity build

Tags: java, svn, diff, teamcity

How to execute "svn diff" inside some custom Junit as part of Teamcity build.

I would like to getwhat has been changed between current version & previous version of file.

I know Teamcity when ran in checkout mode, it checkout full repo then applies the changes.
Would like to get the diff, before it applies changes & stores the file.

Could you give any idea on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your options seem to be:

- execute svn client process from within your test. Make sure you use agent-side checkout in TeamCity and install the client on the agent computer since TeamCity uses a Java library instead of the svn client.
- use TeamCity's teamcity.build.changedFiles.file build [parameter](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Predefined+Build+Parameters). But that will only list the files changes since previous build of the same build configuration
- use TeamCity's [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin) to list changes and then get their files
- write a TeamCity Java plugin that will get the files information from its open API and supply that to the build

Comment: Thank you for providing the way of accessing file.

Comment: . .. With changedFiles build parameter, I could reach to updated modified content of file by framing exact absolute path of the file located on agent by mapping to workingDir . But since my both checkoutDir & workingDir are pointing to same location on agent, seems like my current remote-run changes to the file is getting mergerd & getting stored in one place. Any idea to see it as 2 different files so that I can get diff b/w the current version & previous committed version.